# .append() runns multiple times instead of once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

If you look through this bit of script where you see `alert('hey');`, this is appending five times in the head of the document. It doesn't cause any problem but i want to know how to make it happen only once.

```
$('#logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).animate({ top: "-=20px" },{
        duration: 1000, 
        specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
            complete: function () {
                $(this).animate({ top: "63px" },{
                duration: 1000, 
                specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });
                $('.home,.about,.investments,.media,.contact').animate({ top: "+=106px" },{
                duration: 2000, 
                specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeOutQuad'},     
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#ballTarp').remove();
                        $("head").append( '<link href="css/hoverStates.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' );
                        alert('hey');
                        $('#ball').removeClass('home').addClass('activeHome');
                        $('.activeTitle').fadeIn("fast");
                        $('.dropShadow').fadeIn(7000);
                        $('footer').fadeIn("fast");
                        $('.title').fadeIn("slow");
                        $('.login').fadeIn(3000);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

it's calling the complete function for each of your selectors (.home, .about, .investments, .media, .contact).

That is why it is appending 5 times.

This should work...

```
$('#logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
    $(this).animate({ top: "-=20px" },{
    duration: 1000, 
    specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
        complete: function () {
            $(this).animate({ top: "63px" },{
            duration: 1000, 
            specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
            $('.home,.about,.investments,.media,.contact').animate({ top: "+=106px" },{
            duration: 2000, 
            specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeOutQuad'},     
                complete: function () {
                    $('#ballTarp').remove();
                    // not here...
                    $('#ball').removeClass('home').addClass('activeHome');
                    $('.activeTitle').fadeIn("fast");
                    $('.dropShadow').fadeIn(7000);
                    $('footer').fadeIn("fast");
                    $('.title').fadeIn("slow");
                    $('.login').fadeIn(3000);
                }
            }, function(){
                // but here...
                $("head").append( '<link href="css/hoverStates.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' );
                alert('hey');

            });
        }
});
```

Comment: WOW I amaze myself sometimes

Comment: So yeah, thing is i need it to happen once that part of the animation is complete, Is there any possible way to keep it from happening without changing selectors

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is being run 5 times, once each for every element in your selector.

```
$('.home,.about,.investments,.media,.contact')
```

Answer (score 0):

OK well Thank You @teewuane and @epascarello for making me see the obvious... #brainFart but here is how I fixed it

```
$('#logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).animate({ top: "-=20px" },{
        duration: 1000, 
        specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
            complete: function () {
                $(this).animate({ top: "63px" },{
                duration: 1000, 
                specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeInQuad'},      
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });
                $('.home,.about,.investments,.media,.contact').animate({ top: "+=106px" },{
                duration: 2000, 
                specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutQuad', left: 'easeOutQuad'},     
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#ballTarp').remove();
                        $('#ball').removeClass('home').addClass('activeHome');
                        $('.activeTitle').fadeIn("fast");
                        $('.dropShadow').fadeIn(7000);
                        $('footer').fadeIn("fast");
                        $('.title').fadeIn("slow");
                        $('.login').fadeIn(3000);
                    }
                });
                $("head").append( '<link href="css/hoverStates.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' );
            }
    });
```